# On button click, find element with specific class, and access scope data within element

Tags: html, angularjs

Is it possible to access child elements within a button that has a specific class? There will be multiple buttons created. When a submit button is clicked, I want to iterate through the list of 'btnSelection' buttons created and if a 'btnSelection' button has the 'active' class, I want to push the span data into an array.

I imagine I'd need the parameters put into an object that itself will be a parameter going into the submit method on ng-click, but I'm not sure exactly how to write the Angular portion. Searching Google doesn't yield any specific examples. I'd appreciate any help.

Example HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button id="btnSelection" class="active">
        <span>{{item.value}}</span>
    </button>
</div>
<button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use an active class in you're controller, it's not the angular way. Instead use an active attribute in your items objects and set your active class afterward.

Here is a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L5z3j0gj/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <button type='button' 
                ng-click='addContent($index)'
                ng-class="{active: item.active}"
                ng-disabled='!item.active'>
            <span>{{item.value}}</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <button type='button' ng-click='addContents(items)'>Submit</button>
    {{contentsArray}}
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        { value: 'value1', active: true },
        { value: 'value2', active: false },
        { value: 'value3', active: true }
    ];
    $scope.contentArray = [];

    $scope.addContent = function(index) {
        console.log($scope.items[index]);
        $scope.contentArray.push($scope.items[index].value);
    };

    $scope.addContents = function(items) {
        $scope.contentsArray = [];
        for (var idx in items) {
            var item = items[idx];
            if (item.active) {
                $scope.contentsArray.push(item.value);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.active {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: No, I want the submit button to handle iterating (I imagine with a forEach loop of some kind) through the list of 'btnSelection' buttons and if one of those buttons has an 'active' class, then the span value alone is pushed into an object. This way I don't have to worry about splicing out a particular value if I deselect a specific button.

Comment: @Rex_C, in the "angular way" (MVVM), the view are mere representations of its binded models. Instead thinking that you want the elements within a button with active class, what you really need is the value of each activated item.
The buttons (or whatever is on the view) is only a way to see what the data is.

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bjbrc5wy/3/

```
  <div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <button ng-click="toggleActive(item)" class="active-{{item.active}}">
          {{item.val}}
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

You need to use a controller which acts as a parent object, a container for children. Then when you press your submit button from within this controller, you can access other items from the same controller $scope. You can see I also tie my data to the CSS with `class="active-{{btn.active}}"`, so it automatically updates according to its active status. The controller is defined like so:

```
function ItemCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [ // sample data
    {val:1, active:true},
    {val:2, active:false}];

  $scope.submit = function() {
    var arr = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      if(item.active) arr.push(item.val);
    });
    alert(arr); // here's the array of item values
  };
}
```

Comment: The item.value isn't associated with the 'active' class. 'active' only signifies that the button has been pressed. Once the submit button is pressed, I need the item.value of any button that has been pressed put into an object so I can do an http call to a web service with the values.